# Why won't DatePicker re-open calendar after I hide it?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

1. click button to open calendar
2. Close the calendar on scroll or window resize to avoid some layout issues.
3. Click on the datePicker button and it will not display the calendar.

I am using the same method that closes the calendar when you click outside the control area or by autohide.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example1').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true
  });

  $('#example2').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
  }).on('change', function() {
    $('.datepicker').hide();
  });
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  $('#example2').datepicker("hide");
}, true);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidjmcclelland/nh95p2rv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the button has focus it will not allow another click to display the calendar. Adding a blur allows subsequent clicks.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  $('#example2').datepicker("hide");
  popup.trigger('blur');
}, true);
```